# Environment variables does not update

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two shell scripts. In one of them I have:

```
export FOO="yes"
sh another.sh &

# ops ...

export FOO=0
```

In the `another.sh` I have:

```
while [[ $FOO -eq "yes" ]]
do
# something ...
done
```

The thing is, when the first script finishes, setting `FOO=0`, the value of `FOO` in `another.sh` continues being `"yes"`. I want to know how to get the updated `FOO` so I can figure out when the first script (the caller) has finished.

Comment: In general, you *CAN'T* export an environment variable from one running shell to another.  SUGGESTION: for two independent shell scripts, use a named pipe: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash.  In this particular case, you *CAN* pass the variable from parent to child by substituting `. another.sh &` ("." instead of "sh").

Comment: the variable values are set when the script fires up, and then cannot be changed from the outside. you'd need some other external method of sharing data, like a file somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child process receives a copy of its parent's environment, not references to the original. If the parent changes while the child is still running, the child still has the original values in its memory space.

As a workaround, you could have the parent create an empty file in a known location before it exits, and have the child look for that file to be created. It's not very robust, but it's a simple form of interprocess communication that may be sufficient.

Comment: I thought in doing that before but didn't like the idea to create a file. But in the end I used this as it is a simple way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible: changes to the parent's environment are not passed on to child processes.

Have you considered inverting the parent and child relationship? If the child is waiting for the parent to finish, why not call what was the parent script from what was the child script? Assuming your first script was called "first.sh", something like

another.sh:

```
sh first.sh &
CHILDPID=$!

while ! (ps -p $CHILDPID | grep $CHILDPID)
do
[...]
done
```

Using job control (using `set -m` in bash) may be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Piped `while-read' loop starts subshell
Try to use other loop mechanism instead
Something like:

while read fileName
do
.........
done < <(ls -1tr $SOURCE_DIR)